# Get the data from eclipse ditto to apache IoTDB/ InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb, apache-iotdb, eclipse-ditto

I'm currently working on a project that involves integrating Eclipse Ditto with Apache IoTDB or InfluxDB (or any other suitable DB if not possible in these two). I need to transfer data from Eclipse Ditto to DB to leverage its time-series data storage and analysis capabilities. However, I couldn't find any direct integration options between the two platforms.

I would appreciate guidance on the best approach to achieve this data transfer. Specifically, I want to understand how to:

1. Connect and establish communication between Eclipse Ditto and DB.
2. Define the data model and schema in DB to accommodate the data from Eclipse Ditto.
3. Implement a data ingestion mechanism to transfer real-time data from Ditto to DB.

Optionally, if required, retrieve historical data from DB and expose it through Ditto.